# MVVM: OnBindingContextChange: PropertyChanged not firing in new view model

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I am coding a Xamarin app and doing my best to adhere to MVVM, which I actually really like

I commonly have ContentPages containing references to Views.

I set the binding context to a VM in the Page, and then make use of OnBindingContextChanged in the view

This allows me to use PropertyChanged method to then respond to display logic conditions for my View

I've used it several times successfully but I am baffled why an additional implementation isn't working

Page looks like this

```cs
public partial class BindingTextPage : ContentPage
{
    public BindingTextPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.LocationsViewModel();
    }
}
```

View looks like this

```cs
private LocationsViewModel_vm;

public BindingTestView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Initialised BindingTesView view");

}

protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: BindingTest: OnBindingContextChanged: Context " + this.BindingContext.GetType());

    _vm = BindingContext as LocationsViewModel;

    _vm.PropertyChanged += _vm_PropertyChanged;
}

private void _vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: BindingTest: Method called");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: BindingTest: Property " + e.PropertyName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: BindingTestView: Error changing context " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Extract of view model, very simply in this case setting a string and hence changing a property, which I would have expected would then cause PropertyChange to fire?

```cs
public LocationsViewModel()
{
    tempMessage = "this is from the view model";
}

public string tempMessage
{
    get
    {
        return _tempMessage;
    }
    set
    {
        _tempMessage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(tempMessage));
    }
}
```

My debug statements when it boots up shows that OnBindingContextChange is being called, but in this one instance _vm_PropertyChanged never fires? I'd expect tempMessage being set to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of events in your code is the following

- Constructor of `LocationsViewModel` is called
- From your constructor, you are setting `tempMessage`
- The setter of `tempMessage` calls `OnPropertyChanged`, since the event is `null` at the time being, it's not fired
- Constructor of `LocationsViewModel` is left
- `Page.BindingContext` is set
- `OnBindingContextChanged` is called
- `LocationsViewModel.PropertyChanged` is subscribed by your page

Since the event is raised (or it's tried to) before your page subscribes to, your page simply does not get informed about the event being raised. If you set the value after the event has been subscribed to, the handler will be called as expected.

e.g.

```cs
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    _vm = BindingContext as LocationsViewModel;

    _vm.PropertyChanged += _vm_PropertyChanged;

    _vm.tempMessage = "Hello, world!"; // clichée , I know
}
```

Comment: I figured it had to have something to do with the ordering of events - In almost every other case of using this there's a call going on to an API or a response to a button click. I mistakenly believed setting the value of tempMessage in the constructor would happen asynchronously, but I understand my error now. thank you

Comment: Override OnPropertyChanged to track the property name "BindingContext" as a workaround.